# How to merge multiple query results into one

Tags: mysql, group-by, count

1.

```
SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
```

2.

```
SELECT SUM( inscan ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
```

3.

```
SELECT SUM( is_deliver ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
```

4.

```
SELECT SUM( is_rto ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
```

How To merge above 4 query into one?

I tried below query but it gives Error
"**Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now**"

```
SELECT prtner_name, (

SELECT COUNT( * ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
) AS total, (

SELECT SUM( inscan ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
) AS inscan, (

SELECT SUM( is_deliver ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
) AS deliver, (

SELECT SUM( is_rto ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
) AS rto

FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `FROM`, `WHERE` and `GROUP BY` clause are identical, combine them as follows:

```
SELECT
    prtner_name,
    COUNT(*)        shipment_count,
    SUM(inscan)     inscan_count,
    SUM(is_deliver) is_deliver_count,
    SUM(is_rto)     is_rto_count 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi all query will be merge like this

```
SELECT    prtner_name, 
          count(id)       AS cnt, 
          SUM(inscan)     AS inscan, 
          SUM(is_deliver) AS deliver , 
          SUM(is_rto)     AS rto
FROM     `tbl_shipment`
WHERE    `awdno`       != ''
AND      `prtner_name` != ''
GROUP BY `prtner_name`
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do with subselects.

Example, with your queries:

```
SELECT

(SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name) AS total,

(SELECT SUM( inscan ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name) AS inscan,

(SELECT SUM( is_deliver ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name) AS deliver,

(SELECT SUM( is_rto ) 
FROM tbl_shipment
WHERE  `awdno` !=  '' AND  `prtner_name` !=  ''
GROUP BY prtner_name) AS rto
```

Comment: your query not working get same error

Comment: Sorry @PrAtikLochawala, I think the query is correct. You may have an error in the code that do the query, see this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commands-out-of-sync.html